# Installation directory

Tags: apache-kafka, installation, confluent-platform

I installed the `.deb` package for `Ubuntu 16.04` of `confluent 4.1`
 I am able to get through the `quickstart` fine. However, some things require `env` variable to be set:

```
$CONFLUENT_HOME is not defined. Run 'export CONFLUENT_HOME=/path/to/confluentplatform'
```

I looked in:

```
/opt
/usr/local
/usr/lib
```

but nowhere to be found. I then tried:

```
idf@idf-vb:~$find / -iname confluence  2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

still nothing. Trying:

```
idf@idf-vb:~$ find / -iname confluent  2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"

/var/log/confluent
/home/idf/Documents/confluent
/home/idf/Documents/confluent/quickstart-demos/connect-streams-pipeline/src/main/java/io/confluent
/home/idf/Documents/confluent/quickstart-demos/connect-streams-pipeline/src/main/resources/avro/io/confluent
/usr/bin/confluent
```

I did find

```
idf@idf ls /etc/confluent-common/
```

but there is nothing inside that directory

Other than the `/usr/bin` directory of the executable, which hardly seems like the `home` directory, nothing still. The `confluent` directory under `idf` are just examples.

Where do I find my installation directory?

**EDIT 1**

After doing

```
idf@idf-vb:~$ find / -iname confluent*  2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

I do get a bunch of directories, but still unsure which the `HOME` dir is:

```
idf@idf-vb:~/Documents/confluent$ find / -iname confluent*  2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/confluent-zookeeper.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/confluent-kafka.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/confluent-schema-registry.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/confluent-ksql.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/confluent-kafka-connect.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/confluent-kafka-rest.service.dsh-also
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-schema-registry.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-storage-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-ksql.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-ksql.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-s3.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-cli.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-storage-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-ksql.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-ksql.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-rest.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-rest.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-rest-utils.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-schema-registry.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-platform-oss-2.11.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-2.11.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-rest.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-cli.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-rest.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-schema-registry.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-s3.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-schema-registry.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-camus.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-camus.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-2.11.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-camus.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-rest.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-ksql.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-ksql.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-connect-s3.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-platform-oss-2.11.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-2.11.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-schema-registry.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-rest-utils.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-rest.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-2.11.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-schema-registry.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-kafka-2.11.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/confluent-common.list
/var/log/confluent
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-connect-s3_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-2.11_1.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-cli_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-camus_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-ksql_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-common_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-connect-storage-common_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-platform-oss-2.11_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-schema-registry_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-kafka-rest_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/confluent-rest-utils_4.1.1-1_all.deb
/lib/systemd/system/confluent-schema-registry.service
/lib/systemd/system/confluent-kafka-rest.service
/lib/systemd/system/confluent-zookeeper.service
/lib/systemd/system/confluent-kafka-connect.service
/lib/systemd/system/confluent-ksql.service
/lib/systemd/system/confluent-kafka.service
/tmp/confluent.Gv3442C2
/tmp/confluent.current
/etc/confluent-common
/home/idf/Documents/confluent
/home/idf/Documents/confluent/quickstart-demos/images/confluent-logo-300-2.png
/home/idf/Documents/confluent/quickstart-demos/connect-streams-pipeline/src/main/java/io/confluent
/home/idf/Documents/confluent/quickstart-demos/connect-streams-pipeline/src/main/resources/avro/io/confluent
/usr/bin/confluent
/usr/share/java/confluent-common
/usr/share/java/camus/confluent-camus-4.1.1.jar
/usr/share/doc/confluent-schema-registry
/usr/share/doc/confluent-camus
/usr/share/doc/confluent-common
/usr/share/doc/confluent-ksql
/usr/share/doc/confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch
/usr/share/doc/confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs
/usr/share/doc/confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc
/usr/share/doc/confluent-kafka-connect-storage-common
/usr/share/doc/confluent-kafka-rest
/usr/share/doc/confluent-platform-oss-2.11
/usr/share/doc/confluent-cli
/usr/share/doc/confluent-kafka-connect-s3
/usr/share/doc/confluent-kafka-2.11
/usr/share/doc/confluent-rest-utils
/usr/share/doc/kafka/confluent-support-metrics-client
/usr/share/confluent-common
idf@idf-vb:~/Documents/confluent$
```

A reasonable guess is this one since there is stuff in it:

```
idf@idf-vb:~/Documents/confluent$ ls /usr/share/java/confluent-common
build-tools-4.1.1.jar    common-metrics-4.1.1.jar  jline-0.9.94.jar  netty-3.10.5.Final.jar  zkclient-0.10.jar
common-config-4.1.1.jar  common-utils-4.1.1.jar    log4j-1.2.17.jar  slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar    zookeeper-3.4.10.jar
idf@idf:~/Documents/confluent$
```

Comment: Found using Google: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-home-and-other-important-directories-590259707.html

Comment: Unfortunately that document doesn't say where the directory is.

Comment: Aye, but it names files found inside the installation folder.  You can search for those.

Comment: Not clear. The problem is that as the versions have changed, so has the directory structure. Further, the open source version and the enterprise version may differ. I have already tried the obvious search. Worth a try though....

Comment: See post for update.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that even though there are two options to install confluent, the .`deb/rpm` package etc, and the `.tgz file`, some example programs appears to require that you to download the .`tgz` file and make the directory it creates the `HOME` directory.

The package installation is misleading in that AFAIK, there is no way to create a `HOME` directory.

At least for now, I suggest just downloading the `.tgz` file.

Answer (score 1):

I have also installed confluent using a package, and it seems that CONFLUENT_HOME is / (ROOT)

If you don't want to create an env variable you can pass --path /

```
confluent local list connectors --path /
```